# Show MySQL Column data on select box change using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have the below code that displays a html select box with values from a MySQL Database using a PHP While loop

```
<select name="badge">
    <option value="">Please Choose...</option>
    <?php
    $sql2="SELECT * from badges order by name ASC ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$result2["sequence"].'">'.$result2["name"].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

in my badges table i have the following columns

1. sequence
2. name
3. notes

when the value in the select box changes i want to be able to display the notes column for the selected row

I currently have this but its not using the data from the MySQL table

```
<select id="select_test" name="form_select">
       <option value="0">No</option>
       <option value ="1">Yes</option>
    </select>

    <div id="div1" style="display: none;">hidden text</div>

<script>
        document.getElementById('select_test').addEventListener('change', function () {
            var style = this.value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = style;
        });
</script>
```

how can i do the above with MySQL?

here is what it looks like with the normal HTML:

*http://jsfiddle.net/qHMJg/*

Comment: I am sorry but i dont quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to get the notes from your mysql table when a user picks? I.e update the div1's "hidden text" with whatever is in the mysql database's notes for that value?

Comment: Yes, i am sorry for the late response.

Comment: thats okk - im not so great with javascript so i dont think i will be able to write anything for that part :)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you cant access the MySQL server from the browser. I'm using jquery for my example, you can convert it to raw javascript(Or comment here if you are unable to), but i highly recommend you use jQuery.(As i dont have much time i cant give you exact code for the JS, i will update the answer tomorrow with it if you need)

Once the condition for the element(If you want any) is met, you can use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (If you dont wanna use jquery, you can use the native [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)) to call your server. Depending on the response, you can then update the div1 element.

You can query another page, written specifically to answer to the ajax. You can use this code for the php page. Replace $_GET with $_POST if you are using POST, or 'sequence' with whatever name you gave to the ajax call

```
$sql2="SELECT * from badges WHERE `sequence` = {$_GET['sequence']}";
$sql2=mysql_real_escape_string($sql2); // This is to prevent SQL injection should a hacker send bad data to your .php file
$rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
echo $result2["notes"];
```

Ps: I highly recommend using PDO for mysql. It is much more convenient and safer.

Then, once you have received the ajax reply, simply substitute the value in the div with what the server replied to you

Comment: `$sql2="SELECT * from badges WHERE sequence = $_GET['sequence']";` will not work. Array value must be inserted in the string as `{$array['index']}` not as just `$array['index']`. With the way you are using, you will get the sring `SELECT * from badges WHERE sequence = Array['sequence']` or something like this, or PHP error "Unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE".

Comment: My bad, been a bit clumsy lately. Updated

Comment: i had this before - http://pastebin.com/ZEUWNvMJ - that used 2 tables and changed the second select box based on the selected of the first one